# Creating a web server control to mimic jquery autocomplete API

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, jquery-autocomplete, custom-server-controls

I am attempting to create a ASP .Net (VB.Net) custom control for an auto-complete drop down that uses [jQuery auto-complete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default).

The basic flow is the consumer of the control will set some properties (such as the data source) which will then be injected as javascript to initialize the autocomplete.

There are a lot of pieces involved so i may have missed posting some of the code, please comment if you think something is missing and i will add it.

the consumer's code behind (PreInit event):

```
myDropDown.DataCallback = "testFunc";
```

the DataCallback property in the control:

```
Public Property DataCallback As String
```

the options object creation and javascript injection in the control code behind (PreRender event):

```
Dim _serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim optionsObject As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
optionsObject.Add("source", DataCallback)
Dim optionsJSON = _serializer.Serialize(optionsObject)

Dim initializeScript = String.Format("initialize('{0}', {1});", ClientID, optionsJSON)
Attributes.Add("onfocusin", initializeScript)
```

and finally, the javascript:

```
var initialize = function (controlID, options) {
    if (options) {
        $('#' + controlID).autocomplete(options);
    }

    // remove the blur event handler that called this initialize function
    $('#' + controlID).removeAttr('onfocusin');
};
```

when i debug into the `initialize` function, i see `options` has one property, `source`, with the string `"testFunc"` as it's value. what i need is for `source`'s value to be `testFunc` (not as a string) so it can be executed as a callback in autocomplete instead of autocomplete thinking it is a URL.

Comment: It would be useful to know the type of `_serializer`. There's no way `optionsObject` would serialize correctly into a useful JSON object for jQuery UI if you're using `DataContractJsonSerializer`. The solution is also going to require you to remove the quotation marks around the data callback function name to turn it from a string into an object reference.

Comment: _serializer is a `JavaScriptSerializer` (from `System.Web.Script.Serialization`), i have updated the question with this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to correct this is with a bit of pattern recognition. Your problem arises because the string property is being serialized as a string and enclosed in quotation marks. You instead want it to represent an object reference, which means getting rid of those quotes. To remove the quotation marks, there's a simple regular expression you can apply to the serialized object string:

```
Dim optionsJSON = _serializer.Serialize(optionsObject)
optionsJSON = Regex.Replace(optionsJSON , "(?<=""source"":)""(.+?)""", "$1")
```

What this will do is look for the quoted string preceded by the text `"source":` and capture what's inside to capture group #1. It will then replace that entire match with the inner text, effectively removing the quotes from either side of the callback function's name.

Comment: thanks for your input, i am currently doing something similar by `eval`ing the function name on the javascript side, but this approach may be cleaner. if there are no better solutions posted for a little while, i will accept this as the best possible way.

Comment: @jbabey There's no way to indicate to the `JavaScriptSerializer` that you intend to reference a variable name. One way or another, you'll be doing string manipulation, either in script or in code. The other thing you need to consider is whether or not that variable will be in scope at the time of execution. Another alternative is to restructure your control to make it function as a databound control rather than setting the data source in client script. That would be the approach I'd use if creating the control from scratch.